# Yii2 Kartik Gridview + Select2 filter

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have a Yii2 app and on one of my index views (modified version of the default crud generated with `gii` cli tool) I've replaced the `GridView` widget with the Kartik one, and likewise set a column to use the `filterType` of `GridView::FILTER_SELECT2`

My issue is that when passing an array to the column without the `filterType` I get a select menu, with a blank option to "clear" the search filter:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'scale_id',
    'label' => 'Scale',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return empty($model->scale) ? null : $model->scale->name;
    },
    'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Scale::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
],
```

However, by changing the filter to Kartik's select2 one that empty option doesn't appear and the same behavior doesn't apply:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'scale_id',
    'label' => 'Scale',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return empty($model->scale) ? null : $model->scale->name;
    },
    'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Scale::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
],
```

How would I achieve the same "blank unless changed" select filters with Kartik's select2 filter?

**Update:**
Combining `prompt` with `allowClear` recreates similar functionality, but it's still not ideal. The initial display looks like this:
[image: Initial View]
However, once options have been selected, the close `x` doesn't fit right and overlays the text, as well as not providing the original behavior of having a blank/null value in the dropdown:
[image: Options Selected]

Here is my code for the `GridView`

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [

        'id',
        'description',
        'sku_number',
        [
            'attribute' => 'owner_id',
            'label' => 'Owner',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->owner->name;
            },
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Owner::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'options' => ['prompt' => ''],
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'product_id',
            'label' => 'Product',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->product->name;
            },
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Product::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'options' => ['prompt' => ''],
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'manufacturer_id',
            'label' => 'Manufacturer',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return $model->manufacturer->name;
            },
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Manufacturer::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'options' => ['prompt' => ''],
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'scale_id',
            'label' => 'Scale',
            'value' => function($model) {
                return empty($model->scale) ? null : $model->scale->name;
            },
            'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Scale::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
            'filterWidgetOptions' => [
                'options' => ['prompt' => ''],
                'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
            ],
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
    ],
]); ?>
```

Comment: I think you need to use the `"allowClear"=>true` under the `pluginOptions` for the `select2`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I tried that (and use it in other select2 widgets) but it wouldn't let it clear, as there was no null/clear value. I'll try combining it with `prompt` later.

Comment: you need to provide a `prompt` or `placeholder` in order to let it clear, as it requires a blank option to reset to

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam combining the `prompt` and the `allowClear` did make it work, though the `x` is quite squished. The automatic table sizing isn't working well so I'll need to adjust. Is there no way to get the blank entry you can select from the dropdown like the default does?

Comment: can you show the screen grab for the current display, as far as i know if you assign width auto it will expand according to the length of placeholder or the selected value/option

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I added some pictures and descriptions of what I'm seeing. If I can figure out how to make the selects have the appropriate spacing, it may be a suitable replacement.

Comment: what looks like your first 3 columns are taking up the space and select2 obviously isnt getting the required space to display properly i wont say its select2 fault, you can reduce the input width for the id and sku so that the space can be adjusted.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I updated my question with the code for it. I'm not setting any widths for everything, it's automatically setting the widths you see. Any ideas?

Comment: try using `'filterInputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'width:50px'],` for the `id` column and see what diff it makes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `"allowClear"=>true` options under the `pluginOptions` for `Select2` along with the `"prompt"=>''`.

To adjust the column sizes try using `filterInputOptions` for the `id`, and the `manufacturer_id` to adjust their width as they are taking more space than required and the select2 is squeezed.

```
[
    'attribute' => 'id',
    'filterInputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'width:50px'],
],
[
    'attribute' => 'manufacturer_id',
    'filterInputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'width:50px'],
],
[
    'attribute' => 'scale_id',
    'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Scale::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
    'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
    'filterWidgetOptions' => [
        'options' => ['prompt' => ''],
        'pluginOptions' => [
            'allowClear' => true,
            'width'=>'resolve'
        ],
    ],
],
```

**Update**

Ensure a better width defaulting for `GridView::FILTER_SELECT2`. Set `pluginOptions['width']` to  `default` to resolve. I have updated the code above for the `scale_id` see [here](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-grid/issues/311)

**Update 2**

Apparently, it does not work with `resolve` as it makes the select2 width crazy wide, and you might need to set it manually like `'width' => '200px'`

Comment: Just setting the `id` width isn't enough, but I'll mess with the sizing to try and get them right.

Comment: No good, that causes that one column to grow super wide (1000%?) and push off screen

Comment: @sharf hmm... i just tried it it does look weird , but if you provide manual width here like `'width' => '200px',` i think it should adjust accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Change your Data Column As

```
[
   'attribute' => 'scale_id',
   'label' => 'Scale',
   'value' => function($model) {
           return empty($model->scale) ? null : $model->scale->name;
    },
   'filter' => ArrayHelper::map(Scale::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
   'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
   'filterWidgetOptions' => [
      'options' => ['prompt' => '']
   ]
],
```

Please us `filterWigetOptions` [DataColumn](http://demos.krajee.com/grid#data-column)

Comment: This starts me with a blank input, which is a big help, but doesn't let me clear the input once it's been selected. I'll try combining it with `allowClear` later.

Comment: combining `prompt` with `allowClear` is working, although it's not ideal. If you can update your answer I'll accept it.